# jQuery fileupload can't retrieve the file

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am trying to set up a simple upload with a progress bar (nothing fancy, I don't need the drag and drop or multiple file), to do so I am using blueimp fileupload. I've set it up this way:

```
$(function() {
    $('#fileUpload').fileupload({
        maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/server/php/index.php',
        add: function (e, data) {
            data.context = $('#fileUpload-txt');
            data.context.text('Uploading...');
            data.submit();
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
            $('#progress .bar p').text(progress + '%');
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            data.context.text('Upload complete.');
        },
        fail: function (e, data) {
            alert('Fail!');
        }
    });
});
```

When I upload a file the progress bar becomes green correctly and hit the 100%.

Now, I need to retrieve the file with PHP however it always return an empty array.

Is there something that I am missing to get this working ?

Comment: And where's the PHP that is supposed to catch the file ?

Comment: I added the PHP test that I am running along with the HTML code

Comment: It isn't necessary or desirable that you put in "Edit" tags in your text. If it's necessary, we can see your edits. Instead, put the information into the text as if you'd added it initially. SO is a reference book in progress, so write clearly and concisely, putting information where it belongs and makes sense. Perhaps, because you aren't getting answers, maybe you should work on the problem more on your own prior to asking a question and repeatedly modifying it. Once you've determined the problem you can't solve then ask. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 might help.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research, I finally found my error. The input name MUST be files, so by simply changing it accordingly, it is now working perfectly fine.